# Python geo-maps + 3D engine for a multi-user web application

Tags: python, unity-game-engine, 3d, gis, panda3d

I am looking for a 3D engine for Python but have no idea which one to choose. 
I know that similar questions have been posted about this in the past but they seem to be quite dated now. I thought people might know of new environments out there.

The engine would need to be:
A. In Python
B. Able to draw maps in 3D - by that I mean display basic layers showing roads, blocks and perhaps existing buildings by entring some coordinate / post code
C. Plot 3D objects (pushed from my code)
D. Published to a web browser and ran by multiple users

If anyone knows of any way for using Python in Unity - that would also be grand!

Comment: doesn't look like you can use python in Unity: https://forum.unity.com/threads/python-in-unity.528764/

Answer (score 0):

Try [Panda3D](https://docs.panda3d.org/1.10/python/introduction/index):

> Panda3D is a 3D engine: a library of subroutines for 3D rendering and game development. The library is C++ with a set of Python bindings. Game development with Panda3D usually consists of writing a Python or C++ program that controls the Panda3D library.
>
> Panda3D was created for commercial game development and is still used for developing commercial games. Because of this, the engine needs to emphasize four areas: power, speed, completeness, and error tolerance. Everyone knows what power and speed are. But completeness and error tolerance deserve some extra commentary.

Comment: Thanks @Peter - I know of Panda3D but wasn't sure how workable it is with Python (I know it was mainly a C++ library). My tool is fairly simple but the back-end is already written in Python. I guess my main questions are - how robust is it in getting real geo-spatial data and projecting 3D maps? B. How 'natural' is it in Python?

Comment: > "Will be very easy for developers already familiar with Python
Although it's possible to use only C++ to program in Panda3D, all its power is available to the Python scripting language, while not trading in performance since the performance-critical parts are implemented in C++. It has a powerful binding layer that exposes the vast majority of the API via Python-based interfaces." [From slant.co](https://www.slant.co/topics/10908/~game-engines-for-python).